# Swagger UI in Spring: only HTML file is loaded, but not the resources

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

I am using Springfox Swagger. This is what I see when I access http://localhost:8088/myContextRoot/swagger-ui.html:

[image]

I.e. only the HTML file `swagger-ui.html` is loaded successfully, other stuff (js, css, etc.) which supposed to be at http://localhost:8088/myContextRoot/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui returns 404.

What I've tried so far:

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/swagger-ui.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webjars/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

resources-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

Java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
         @Override
         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
              http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security/**",
                        "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
                .permitAll();
         }
    }
```

Versions used:

```
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into this class `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController`, you can find that mappings like `/configuration/ui` and `/configuration/security` don't exist anymore (in `io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:2.6.1`), because they was changed on `/swagger-resources/configuration/ui` and `/swagger-resources/configuration/security` respectively according to Spring Request Mapping

Try to use this Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem when upgrade `springfox-swagger2` from `2.7.0` to `2.8.0`。

I fixed it by just clean `Chrome Web Browser` cookie and sessions。